# TypeError: translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'

Tags: python, json, google-translate

I have just started using python a few days ago and unfortunately, I can't figure out what's wrong with this code.
I am using the google trans API to translate from french to german.
My code is pretty simple and I don't see anything wrong with it. My whole console says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\...", line 7, in <module>
    t = translator.translate(text,dest ="de", src = "fr")
TypeError: translate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'
[Finished in 0.437s]
```

```
from googletrans import Translator 
translator = Translator      
text = "je suis"

t = translator.translate(text,dest ="de", src = "fr")
```

dest is the destination language of the translator it is required by the translate function. In this case, german
scr is the source language, in this case french.
text is the text to be translated.

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: What is dest and src parameter, where did you find from ?

Comment: Don't you miss the brackets; `translator = Translator()` ?

Comment: Follow this https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: When I add the parentheses to `Translator()` it works just fine. I'm on macOS, Python 3.8.2, googletrans 2.4.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing brackets when creating your 'translator' object.

It should be:

```
translator = Translator()
```

which injects the 'self' argument in. This is why you're getting the missing argument error.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-in-python-class/

If you're getting a JSON decode error following that it's likely that you're inputing the wrong argument type somewhere to 'Translator'. Make sure you have read the usage and you're providing the JSON object as an argument where it's needed.